# MapBox in Swift - Allowing a marker's annotation to have a button that links to a View

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, mapbox-marker

I have set up a simple app with a tabbed map view (map on tab 1) that reads info from a json file on a server (point info is stored in MySQL) with SwiftyJSON and Alamofire. The points are loaded into the map. What I would like to do is add a button to the annotation, which outlets to a different view tab and passes along the point's ID.

I have not tried anything yet as I have no idea where to get started and the documentation doesn't mention anything similar.

How does one go about adding an outlet to a map point annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you tap your pin the callout appears with a title and/or a subtitle. You need to add left and right callout accessory views to this callout. You do this by conforming to the MGLMapViewDelegate and implementing the following methods:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, annotationCanShowCallout annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> Bool {
        return true
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, leftCalloutAccessoryViewFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> UIView? {
    ...your code here...
    let deleteButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
    deleteButton.tag = 100
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, rightCalloutAccessoryViewFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> UIView? {
    ...your code here...
    let infoButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
    infoButton.tag = 101
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, annotation: MGLAnnotation, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    ...your code here...
    switch control.tag {
    case 100:
       // do some delete stuff
    case 101:
       // do some info stuff
    default:
       break 
}
```

The MapBox example showing actual usage is here:
[MapBox example](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/callout-delegate/). This example doesn't segue but you would just trigger a segue with the button tap instead of the UIAlert.

Comment: Thank you! I will add an additional answer with the segue code.

Comment: In `calloutAccessoryControlTapped`, how do you determine if the left or the right accessory was tapped?

Comment: @keverley - I've added some more to my answer above. I just used tags but there is probably a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, annotation: MGLAnnotation, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    // Hide the callout view.
    // mapView.deselectAnnotation(annotation, animated: true)

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toDetail", sender: view)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    print("Seque toDetail")
    // do stuff
}
```